# How to get a single random value from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, chatterbot

I'm trying to get a single response from an array of responses. I've tried using the `random.choice()` but i'm getting errors. When i print the response without the `random.choice()` it prints out the entire array `"responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, "],`
My code

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot 
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer 
import chatterbot #Just in case
import os
import random


bot = ChatBot("Test") 
trainer = ListTrainer(bot) #Creates the trainer
data = "C:/Users/Patty/Desktop/chatbotUI/ints/"

for files in os.listdir(data):
    conv = open(data + files, 'r').readlines() 
    trainer.train(conv) 


while True:
    message = input("You: ")

    if message.strip() != "Bye":
        response = bot.get_response(message)
        answer = random.choice(response)
        print("ChatBot: ", answer) 

    if message.strip() == "Bye":
        print("ChatBot: Farewell")
        break
```

Here is my json intents

```
intents = [

{"tag": "greeting",
"patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Whats up"],
"responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, "],
"context_set": ""
},
]
```

Comment: Try `random.choice(list(response[0]['responses']))`

Answer (score 1):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a value from a sequence (like a list).

It looks like you might be passing a nested data structure with a list further inside.

```py
from random import choice

# Is your data like this?
response = [{"responses": ["Hello!", "Good to see you again!", "Hi there, "]}]
print(choice(response))
# > {'responses': ['Hello!', 'Good to see you again!', 'Hi there, ']}

print(choice(response[0]['responses']))
# > Good to see you again!
```

Comment: i'm getting an error saying '   answer = choice(response[0]['responses'])
TypeError: 'Statement' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Looks like you need to look into the docs describing the `Statement` object to try and find out how it works to reach inside of it. You an also try calling `dir` on it, to see what attributes it has.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, response is a dictionary, not an array, so you should change

```py
answer = random.choice(response)
```

to

```py
answer = random.choice(response["responses"])
```

Comment: it brings an error ' answer = random.choice(response["responses"])
TypeError: 'Statement' object is not subscriptable'